# How to send data from serial port to an express api?

Tags: mysql, reactjs, express

Am working on a project which involves reading data from a weighing scale using serial port. I read the data successfully and save's it to a variable but i have a problem sending it to an express api so that it can be saved to mysql database.

How can i send the weight variable to an api so that the weight can be saved?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.